# How to Format a Table in CloudDeploy?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I have used Grid to create and format my table, but the format is lost when the table is moved to the cloud.  How do I get a formatted table to show in the cloud?

Answer (score 2):

Use ExportForm

```
CloudDeploy[ ExportForm[Grid[Map[Flatten[# ] &,test], {Background -> {None,
{{White, 
Lighter[Blend[{Blue, Green}], 0.8`]}}}, 
Dividers -> {{Gray, {LightGray}, Gray}}, Frame -> True, 
Spacings -> {2, {2, {0.7`}, 2}}}], "GIF"]]
```